# Angular2 multiple Observables and forkJoin not working

Tags: angular

I have the following code, where the console.log('data') is never hit. I think it has something to do with the Subject. Can someone help?

```js
    getTextResourceSubject(key: string): Observable<string> {        
        const subject = new Subject<string>();
        // Do something here
        return subject;
    }
    
    
    initialise(title: string, message: string, yes: string, no: string) {
        var titleTranslated: string;
        var messageTranslated: string;
        var yesTranslated: string;
        var noTranslated: string;

        console.log('initialising');
        
        Observable.forkJoin(
            this.getTextResourceSubject(title),
            this.getTextResourceSubject(message),
            this.getTextResourceSubject(yes),
            this.getTextResourceSubject(no)
        ).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log('data');

                titleTranslated = data[0];
                messageTranslated = data[1];
                yesTranslated = data[2];
                noTranslated = data[3];

                console.log(data);
            },
            err => console.log(err)
          );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has something to do with the `Subject`. You need to pass the data into the subject otherwise it does not emit any value and the data is not received. What you need to do to publish the value is

```
mySubject.next(value);
```

Your intention is not quite clear but I assume you want another type of Subject which can be BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject.

This should fix the issue

```
getTextResourceSubject(key: string): Observable<string> {        
    const subject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(key);
    // Do something here
    return subject;
}
```

This will create a Subject which is populated with your `key` value.

Actually I don't see any point of using subjects in your case. You could also try to go with

```
getTextResourceSubject(key: string): Observable<string> {        
    const obs = Observable.of(key);
    // Do something here
    return obs;
}
```